# create a neo4j graph from a csv file containing three columns

Tags: neo4j, apache-zeppelin

I have a csv file containing producers and consumers of some topics. e.g

```
producer,topic,consumer
PRODUCER-1,TOPIC-A,CONSUMER-1
PRODUCER-2,TOPIC-B,CONSUMER-2
PRODUCER-1,TOPIC-C,CONSUMER-3
PRODUCER-1,TOPIC-D,CONSUMER-1
PRODUCER-2,TOPIC-E,CONSUMER-3
```

I am trying to plot a graph using neo4j in Zeppelin notebook to achieve this. I managed to load the csv as shown below but couldn't get the pubsub graph showing the relationship between the producers and consumers via the topics working.

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///data/pubsub.csv' AS row
WITH row[0] AS Producer, row[1] AS Topic, row[2] AS Consumer
RETURN Producer, Topic, Consumer
```

Would appreciate any help please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your Cypher code is only returning the data from the CSV file (without storing it in the DB). Do you just want to graphically *visualize* the data, or do you also want to store the data in the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to first store the dataset into Neo4j and then query it... This will help you with Zeppelin visualizations

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data/pubsub.csv' AS row
MERGE (p:Producer{id:row.producer})
MERGE (t:Topic{id:row.topic})
MERGE (c:Consumer{id:row.consumer})
MERGE (p)-[:PRODUCER]->(t)
MERGE (t)-[:CONSUMER]->(c)
```

Now that you have saved your data into graph, you can try and query it in Zeppelin with:

```
MATCH p=()-->()
RETURN p
```

Comment: Since your CSV has headers you'll want to use `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS`, remove the `WITH` clause and then use `row.producer`, `row.topic`, etc. Otherwise, you'll end up creating nodes whose properties are the actual headers

Comment: Thanks Tomaž Bratanič and hoyski, very helpful

Comment: How do I capture a relationship where a consumer is also producer to another topic pls? Lets say there is a new row,
`CONSUMER-2,TOPIC-F,CONSUMER-5`. I want one graph that includes all nodes including `TOPIC-B<--CONSUMER-2--->TOPIC-F`. At the moment, `CONSUMER-2` is dangling